# Python multipart not working

Tags: php, python-2.7, python-3.x, request, python-requests

**POST DATA**

```
POSTDATA =-----------------------------204994970613471446171879029128
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="f"; filename="shell.php"
Content-Type: application/x-php

<?php
echo("oi");
?>
-----------------------------204994970613471446171879029128
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="v"

up
-----------------------------204994970613471446171879029128--
```

**FORM**

```
<form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data><input type=file name=f><input name=v type=submit id=v value=up>
```

**PYTHON**

```
import requests 
try:
    files = {"f": open("page.php", "rb"),"v":"up"}
    r = requests.post("http://soportetecnico.nixiweb.com/up.php", files=files, headers={"Content-type": "application/x-php"})
    print r.text
except Exception as e:
    print e
```

What i need to send a PHP file to upload with python?
I dont't know what i'm doing wrong.
Thank in advance for help =]

Answer (score 2):

You should separate the `files` and the `data` in your request:

```
import requests 
try:
    files = {"f": open("page.php", "rb")}
    values = {"v":"up"}
    r = requests.post("http://soportetecnico.nixiweb.com/up.php", files=files, data=values, headers={"Content-type": "application/x-php"})
    print r.text
except Exception as e:
    print e
```

Comment: @LeandroCampos, try to open `php` file as simple text `{"f": open("page.php")}`, not as bytes. Same result?

Comment: @LeandroCampos what exactly isn't working? what do you get? any errors? what is the response?

Comment: **Header**
{'Content-Length': '508', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.8.1', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Content-type': 'application/x-php'}

**Response**
<form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data><input type=file name=f><input name=v type=submit id=v value=up><br>

The problem was not uploaded.